# CSS - Animated moving object won't stay where it stopped

Tags: html, css

So I'm fiddling with animations, and I've stumpled upon a problem, after I've moved my object it return to it's initial position. Is there a way to keep it at its final position?

Some of the `CSS` I've got:

```
.spinner-word span {
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    animation: move .5s linear;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        left: -8vw;
    }
    100% {
        left: 0px;
    }
}
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/gkzdy73s/)

Comment: Means you don't want Glu word to come from left to right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count